# Windows 8: full screen image for different devices

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am learning Windows 8 metro style app development, I want to set a background photo in my app, it will fit the full screen, should I provide different sizes of this image so that it can fit all devices? If i should, which detailed sizes should I provide?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I provide different sizes so that it can file all devices?
>   Yes
>
> which detailed sizes:
>   You should provide images that scale for different resolutions as well as sizes. Common sizes include (these come from the Windows 8 simulator - you can test you app with these sizes):

- 1024 x 768
- 1366 x 768
- 1920 x 1080

There are also recommendations for providing images at different resolutions (100, 140, 180 dpi).

Please make sure you check out:

[Guidelines for scaling to screens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780612.aspx)

[Guidlines for scaling to pixel density](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx)